# More than 255 characters in multiple lines of text?

Tags: content-type, infopath, column

I have an InfoPath Form which submits the text of a textbox and saves it in a SharePoint list. Whenever a user types in more than 255 characters and I want to edit the element in the SharePoint list (e.g. change the value of a custom field) an error appears that the textbox cannot contain more than 255 characters.

It's weird because initially the column can contain more than 255 characters but as soon as I want to edit the element, I get this error.

My question is: How can I turn off the limitation OR how can I display a character counter next to my InfoPath textbox?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Another good option from another thread: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185293/how-to-increase-the-number-of-characters-limit-in-hyperlink-column-type?newreg=883386aae84143d389b1df0d2972027c

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to check the "Allow unlimited length" checkbox on the list column's properties page.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine if I create a new column. Unfortunately, I can't change the property for an existing column, is it possible to change it? imagebanana.com/view/7ovt483z/Unbenannt.png

Comment: are you sure you are in the list settings and the clicked the list column? Another thing is you might have enough permissions to do this

Comment: I think the setting cannot be changed on some default columns. On custom column types you should be able to change this setting even after creation.

Comment: Just a short comment: in version SP 2013 this option reads as "Allow unlimited length in document libraries" and as ist name suggests, you have this option only in document libraries, and not at other list types. On the other hand, you don't have the limitations for multiple text fields at other list types, there are "unlimited" in length out-of-the-box, so there is really no need for this option. A useful link: http://www.markrackley.net/2016/06/11/changes-to-multiple-lines-of-text-fields-in-document-libraries-in-office-365/

Answer (score 0):

Forget about InfoPath for a minute. Go directly into the SharePoint list settings and update the field properties. Take out the 255 limitation. Save your changes and then open a new InfoPath form and point it at the list. It will pick up all of your previous changes and as well, your field will not have this 255 length limitation.

Comment: "Take out the 255 limitation." Explaining _how_ to do this (e.g. what steps to take) is the valuable part of the answer that this post is missing.