# How to increase the number of characters limit in hyperlink column type

Tags: 2013, list, column, hyperlink

I am using sharepoint 2013. I have column type `Hyperlink` in a list. It is not taking more than 255 characters for the url. Can I increase the limit? How can I do this using js?

Comment: Similar question is asked before in stackoverflow. Please refer the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424917/long-url-in-sharepoint-for-url-type-field

Answer (score 3):

You can't increase the character limit of the hyperlink column. But you have a workaround for it,

> 1. Add a Multi-Text column to your list
> 2. Edit the item that has long URL
> 3. Go to the Multi-Text field and you will get Rich-Content Ribbon
> 4. Click `Insert` on the Ribbon > Link > To Address
> 5. Add your Title and long URL in the respected field

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424917/long-url-in-sharepoint-for-url-type-field

Comment: can you give the reference? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424917/long-url-in-sharepoint-for-url-type-field

Answer (score 2):

You can not increase the limit.

## Possible workaround

You can use **Multi-Text** column find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16425544/1294606)

**OR**

You can use URL shortener like https://goo.gl/ and then store the URL in your hyperlink column.

Google's URL shortener has JavaScript API. So call this API from your JS code and then store it in your hyperlink column.

https://gist.github.com/hayageek/4584508

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative (only to display a Hyperlink in a **VIEW**) you can use a calculated column, with the datatype set to DateTime (Number will align the HTML to the right) to output it as HTML.

This also has the maximum string length of 255 characters BUT you can concatenate multiple strings up to the maximum Formula length of 4000 bytes

```
="<a href='http://longurl"
 &"longurl_max255_chars"
 &"longurl_max255_chars"
 &"'>UrlName</a>"
```